# Installed Blu-Ray/DVD drive over SATA 3 link, no longer able to boot

Tags: linux, sata, blu-ray

I'm having a really weird problem after installing a new Blu-Ray/DVD drive last night into a SATA 3 port on my desktop.

My installed Linux distribution (Ubuntu 12.04/elementary Luna/kernel 3.7.5) won't boot. It seems to hang after the modeset. I can get to recovery mode with the following kernel options: `nomodeset recovery`. A Fedora 23 MATE Live CD/DVD seems to hang right after finishing the initial bootup loading screen. I can get booted into a Clonezilla Live CD, but I can't get into either my installed Linux or a new Fedora.

In the Clonezilla kernel log, I see that `ata8.0` fails to initialize, saying that an `IDENTIFY PACKET FAILED` or something along those lines. This makes me think that either there's something wrong with the SATA port, the SATA cable, or the Blu-Ray/DVD reader device. Windows 7 on the same machine boots just fine and I can play DVDs in the device without issue.

How can I debug what's actually going wrong so that I can fix it (perhaps with a kernel boot parameter)?

Comment: Try one of the latest kernel 4. I do remember vaguely of a related bug, however I do not have the time now to google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/232149/6645):

> In my case, the motherboard is ASRock Z77 Extreme4 with the same ASMedia ASM1061 chip for two SATA3 ports. I had a DVD drive in one of them and got the error. Switched the DVD drive to a SATA port handled by the Z77 chip and everything works.

Unfortunately, things that we often take for granted like SATA and USB don't always work as reliably as we think that they do.

In my case, my motherboard has two different sets of SATA ports, one run by one type of SATA firmware, the other run by a different type of SATA firmware. Switching the drive from one set of ports to the other fixed my problem.

On a related note, manufacturers of motherboards should *really* just choose the best chipset for the job and use that everywhere.